# How can I ease the syntactic overhead of checking iterator values in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Basically, I'm a bit tired of writing:

```
std::map<key_t, val_t> the_map;
...
auto iterator = the_map.find(...);
if(iterator != the_map.end()) { // note the "inversed" logic and logically superflous end() call
  ...
}
```

What really made sense would be:

```
if(auto x=the_map.find(...)) {
  ... // x could either be an iterator or maybe something like boost::optional<val_t>
}
```

Is there some prior art that defines some helper stuff to shorten the `!= container.end()` syntax or am I the only one annoyed by this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write a class template `auto_iterator_impl` and use it through a function template `auto_iterator` which returns an instance of `auto_iterator_impl`, which can be implicitly converted into `true` or `false`:

A working implementation with minimal functionalities and consideration:

```
template<typename C>
struct auto_iterator_impl
{
    C & c;
    typename C::iterator  it;
    auto_iterator_impl(C & c,  typename C::iterator & it) : c(c), it(it) {}
    operator bool() const { return it != c.end(); }
    typename C::iterator operator->() { return it; }
};

template<typename C>
auto_iterator_impl<C> auto_iterator(C & c, typename C::iterator  it)
{
    return auto_iterator_impl<C>(c, it);
}
```

Test code:

```
void test(std::map<int, int> & m, int key)
{
    if (auto x = auto_iterator(m, m.find(key)))
    {
        std::cout << "found = " << x->second << std::endl;
        x->second *= 100; //change it
    }
    else
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int,int> m;
    m[1] = 10;
    m[2] = 20;  
    test(m, 1);
    test(m, 3);
    test(m, 2);

    std::cout <<"print modified values.." <<std::endl;
    std::cout << m[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << m[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
found = 10
not found
found = 20
print modified values..
1000
2000
```

Online demo : http://www.ideone.com/MnISh

Answer (score 7):

Well, if it means that much to you, how about a little wrapper:

```
template <typename Container>
inline bool find_element(Container const & c,
                         typename Container::const_iterator & it,
                         typename Container::value_type const & val)
{
  return (it = c.find(val)) == c.end();
}
```

Usage:

```
std::vector<int> v;
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;

if (find_element(v, it, 12)) { /* use it */ }
```

Comment: Nim: You're welcome to add specializations that use `std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), val)`, perhaps predicated on a "must use generic `find`" typetrait :-)

Comment: Meh. Need to pre-declare the iterator variable. Brrr! ;-)

Comment: @Martin: It depends if you just want a yes/no, or if you actually want to use the result of the find. If you want to use the result, you have to communicate it somehow... I guess you could write something that returns a *pointer*, and null if not found: `return it == c.end() ? nullptr : &*it;`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the most flexible decision to write a wrapper like

```
template<class Iterable>
bool CheckIterator(const typename Iterable::iterator& iter, const Iterable& collection)
{
    return !(iter == collection.end());
}
```

and use it

```
    map<int,string> m;
    m[1]="hello";
    m[2]="world";
    map<int,string>::iterator it = m.find(2);
    if(CheckIterator(it,m))
    {
        cout<<it->second;
    }
```

it may be used with another types of containers (e.g. vector's) as well

Comment: That may actually be a very nice low-tech solution :-) (Although I'd name it differently.)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
BOOST_FOREACH(auto &x : c.equal_range(...)) {
    // x is a val_t &, or const if c is const.
}
```

I'm assuming that if it's OK for `x` to be `boost::optional<val_t>`, then you don't actually need the iterator, just the value, so a reference is OK.

You can use a C++11 range-based for loop instead of BOOST_FOREACH if you use a `boost::iterator_range` instead of a `std::pair` (which is what `equal_range` returns).

Comment: `c.equal_range(t)` ? Otherwise I applaude the effort of steering people towards ranges :)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a wrapper function to do the `!= map.end()` check for you, or you could use the preprocessor to do it using a macro like this:

```
#define map_find_if(iterator, container, func) \
    auto (iterator) = (func); \
    if ((iterator) != (container).end())
```

Use it like this:

```
map_find_if(iter, map, map.find(key)) {
   // found the key
}
// else clause could go here
```

Using a function is probably a cleaner implementation though, and more in the "C++ way".

Comment: Don't use macros when you can do otherwise, really :x

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to lump your code into an anonymous function (looks like you are using `auto` already, so assuming c++11)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

template <typename Container, typename ExecF>
void exec_if(Container const& cont, typename Container::const_iterator it, ExecF f)
{
  if (it != cont.end())
    f();
}

int main(void)
{
  std::map<int, int> bar;
  bar.insert(std::make_pair(1, 1));
  bar.insert(std::make_pair(2, 2));
  bar.insert(std::make_pair(3, 3));

  auto it = bar.find(2);
  exec_if(bar, it, [&it]()
    { 
      std::cout << it->first << ' ' << it->second << std::endl; 
    });

}
```

EDIT: now I think it's a lot more cleaner